# Flexbox masonry responsive

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, masonry

I am using a Flexbox Masonry to display WordPress posts in a beautiful way, with this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/osj2507/pen/ZYBBpw).
It works well, but I want to make it responsive. I have already changed the CSS for media queries, but how can I adapt the JavaScript columns for mobile, tablet and desktop?  (like mobile 1 column, tablet 2 columns, desktop 3 columns)

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: containerWidth / 3,
  itemSelector: '.flex-item'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really simple way of doing this :) For example run the code when screen is less than `480px`(mobile)

If you have these media queries e.g:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    // styles
}
```

You can use the following javascript code:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480) {
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
      // options
      columnWidth: containerWidth / 3, // you can change 3 to 1 right?
      itemSelector: '.flex-item'
    });
}
```

Do this for mobile, tablet and desktop and you're be good to go :)

Source: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/javascript/conditionally-load-javascript-based-on-media-query

Comment: Thank you! It works well for 2 media queries. What if I want to use a JavaScript like < 480 and >1024 (smaller than 1024px and bigger than 480px)?

Comment: You could just use a code for < 480, < 760, < 960 and > 960 or something. No need for both. It will stop at the next javascript block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery resize() function.
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var window_width = $(window).width();
  if (window_width < 768) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

To change the cloumns first destroy the effect. http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#destroy

In the second step Init the script with 2 cloumns or 5 columns or whatever ;)

Be carefull with the resize function, 'cause you fire that event on every window resize.

You can do that also with matchMedia:

```
/*======================================*/
/*== JS MediaQueries */
/*======================================*/
    if (matchMedia) {
        var mq768 = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 768px)" );
        mq768.addListener(viewport);
        viewport(mq768);
    }   

function viewport(mq768) {

        if (mq768.matches) {
           // do something
        }

}
```

Comment: Will this work in Firefox? I read something a while ago that this did not work with Firefox.

Comment: Works for me in the latest FF (42.0)

Comment: Nice :) Good to know.